# Export-Alias : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Administrator' is denied. Why?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Hey there super user community. I am new to Powershell so I was practicing commands on **ISE** and I got a **error message** for the **command** -

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Write-Host | Export-Alias -Name *
```

**The error message was** -

```
Export-Alias : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Administrator' is denied.
```

Can somebody tell me
**Why is this happening ?** **And How to Fix this ?**

Comment: you are apparently in a directory where you don't have permission to create/write files. add `-Path` and a valid target to your command OR change to a dir that you _do_ have permission to use.

Comment: Thankyou so much for replying.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped somewhat ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Export-Alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-alias?view=powershell-7.1) outputs to a file. It seems that you're trying to output the aliases to the console in which case you should consider the [Get Alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-alias?view=powershell-7.1) command with:

```
Get-Alias
```

Comment: the `-Name` parameter for that cmdlet does NOT refer to the file. [*grin*] lookee >>> `Get-Help Export-Alias -Parameter name` <<< what you are thinking of is the `-Path` parameter.

Comment: Thankyou so much for replying.